# useState dosen't work in react - useSelector, useState, useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, use-effect, use-state

To load more images, the list should accept the values of images, but it's not working.

Why can't I get the value of the list? (list.length=0 in console)

```
  const { images, imagesLoaded } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.gallery);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    if(!imagesLoaded) {
      dispatch(getImages());
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);
  
  const [list, setList] = useState([...images.slice(0, 5)])

  console.log(images.slice(0, 5))
  console.log(list.length)

  const [loadMore, setLoadMore] = useState(false)
  const [hasMore, setHasMore] = useState(images.length > 5)
  const handleLoadMore = () => {
    setLoadMore(true)
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Without context of `getImages()` I assume `images` begins as an empty array?

So on first load `setList` will set nothing and when you console.log, the length will be 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Becasue `images` only has value after you call `dispatch(getImages());`

`const [list, setList] = useState([...images.slice(0, 5)])` will declare the initial value for `list` and not update when `images` update.

if you want update `list` when `images` update, you can use `useEffect`:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setList(images.slice(0, 5))
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [images]);
```